# Filtering a list of images by using a filter and association lists

Tags: python

I've got an assignment and part of it asks to define a process_filter_description. Basically I have a list of images I want to filter:

```
images = ["1111.jpg", "2222.jpg", "circle.JPG", "square.jpg", "triangle.JPG"]
```

Now I have an association list that I can use to filter the images:

```
assc_list = [ ["numbers", ["1111.jpg", "2222.jpg"]] , ["shapes", ["circle.JPG", "square.jpg", "triangle.JPG"]] ]
```

I can use a filter description to select which association list I want to apply the filter the keyword is enclosed by colons):

```
f = ':numbers:'
```

I'm not exactly sure how to start it. In words I can at least think:

- Filter is ':numbers:'
- Compare each term of images to each term associated with numbers in the association list.
- If term matches, then append term to empty list.

Right now I am just trying to get my code to print only the terms from the numbers association list, but it prints out all of them.

```
def process_filter_description(f, images, ia):

    return_list = []

    f = f[1:-1]

    counter = 0

    if f == ia[counter][0]:
        #print f + ' is equal to ' + ia[counter][0]

        for key in ial:
            for item in key[1]:
                #print item
                #return_list.append(item)

    return return_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an "associative list", how about using a dictionary?

```
filter_assoc = {'numbers': ['1111.jpg', '2222.jpg'] ,
                'shapes':  ['circle.JPG', 'square.jpg', 'triangle.JPG']}
```

Now, just see which images are in each group:

```
>>> filter_assoc['numbers']
['1111.jpg', '2222.jpg']
>>>
>>> filter_assoc['shapes']
['circle.JPG', 'square.jpg', 'triangle.JPG']
```

Your processing function would become immensely simpler:

```
def process_filter_description(filter, association):
  return association[filter[1:-1]]
```

---

I'll just think aloud here, so this is what I'd use as a function to perform the task of the dictionary:

```
def process_filter_description(index, images, association):
  return_list = []
  index = index[1:-1]

  for top_level in association:
    if top_level[0] == index:
      for item in top_level[1]:
        return_list.append(item)

      break

  return return_list
```

Comment: Ahh sorry! I should've mentioned I'm not allowed to use dictionaries lol. Just learned it on the Friday, so we're restricted to using lists and iterating over them instead. But I do know the potential of dictionaries now.

Comment: See my edit. That function should work the way you intend, and I used long variable names to make it readable (to me at least).

Comment: I'm getting an empty string returned. Wouldn't top_level be assigned to a list? So a list will never equal index since index is a string. If I replace that line with 'if f in top_level:', then I get the association list back (The one associated with ':numbers:') which is not what I want actually.

Comment: I want to apply the filter, so that if I select ':numbers:', I should only end up with numbers in the end.

Comment: Lol its ok! It actually helped me considerably. I finally got the code to work! I wont post it public for privacy reasons, but if you still want the answer I can pm it over. Thanks a lot for the help! Basically I went one level in at top_level to get into the sublist containing just the terms I need and then compared them to the images.

Comment: I guess my next question is how would I do the same thing but using a counter instead? Cause I know for sure with lists we can say list[i] and that would represent the item in the list at that specific index.

Comment: `for i in list` can be made into a loop: `for i in range(len(list))` and `item = list[i]`.